# Scroll in Kendo Grid Column Menu

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have created a Kendo Grid in jquery which has a large number of columns suppose 50. Initially only 10 will be visible and the end-user can make other columns visible through column menu.

**Problem :**

If the column count is too large like in my case , the columns window in the column menu become too large . What i want is to incorporate a scroll in it.

Below I have shown the image:

[image]

Jquery:

```
 //Creating Kendo Grid For Tasks
            divSearchGrid.kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: function (options) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: urlSearch,
                                data: paramsSearch,
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (result) {

                                    var data = result.d;
                                    if (data != null) {
                                        if (data.length > 0) {
                                            orignalComplexData = data;
                                            structuredData = [];
                                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                                var checkExistance = '';
                                                var objStructured = {};
                                                objStructured['StatusID'] = 1;
                                                objStructured['AttID'] = 1;
                                                objStructured['ServiceDefautltSRSubject'] = data[i].ServiceDefautltSRSubject;
                                                objStructured['IsDescriptionEditable'] = data[i].IsDescriptionEditable;
                                                objStructured['RecordStatusID'] = data[i].RecordStatusID;
                                                objStructured['TaskOrder'] = data[i].TaskOrder;
                                                objStructured[defaultTaskColumnAray[0]] = data[i].ServiceRequestID;
                                                objStructured[defaultTaskColumnAray[1]] = data[i].TaskID;
                                                objStructured[defaultTaskColumnAray[2]] = data[i].TaskDescription;
                                                objStructured[defaultTaskColumnAray[3]] = data[i].FolderDescription;
                                                objStructured[defaultTaskColumnAray[4]] = data[i].FolderSubject;
                                                objStructured[defaultTaskColumnAray[5]] = data[i].AssignedToName;
                                                objStructured[defaultTaskColumnAray[6]] = data[i].StatusName;
                                                objStructured[defaultTaskColumnAray[7]] = data[i].ServiceName;
                                                objStructured['NavigateURI'] = data[i].NavigateURI;
                                                objStructured['SRNavigateURI'] = data[i].SRNavigateURI;
                                                objStructured['NavigateURIPSRID'] = data[i].NavigateURIPSRID;
                                                objStructured['StatusIconpath'] = data[i].StatusIconPath;
                                                objStructured['RecordStatusIcon'] = data[i].RecordStatusIcon;

                                                if (data[i].PSRID != 0) {
                                                    objStructured[defaultTaskColumnAray[8]] = data[i].PSRID;
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    objStructured[defaultTaskColumnAray[8]] = '';
                                                }

                                                objStructured[defaultTaskColumnAray[9]] = data[i].PSRSubject
                                                var customFieldList = data[i].RecordStatusToolTip.split('%');
                                                if (selectedFolderType != '' || defaultServiceGUID != '') {
                                                    for (var j = 0; j < customFieldList.length; j++) {
                                                        var fieldIndex = $.inArray(customFieldList[j].split('||')[0], checkExistance.split(','));
                                                        if (fieldIndex == -1) {
                                                            if (customFieldList[j].split('||')[2] == '5' || customFieldList[j].split('||')[2] == '6') {
                                                                if (customFieldList[j].split('||')[1] == 'true') {
                                                                    objStructured[customFieldList[j].split('||')[0]] = true;
                                                                }
                                                                else {
                                                                    objStructured[customFieldList[j].split('||')[0]] = false;
                                                                }

                                                            }
                                                            else if (customFieldList[j].split('||')[2] == '7') {
                                                                if (customFieldList[j].split('||')[1] != '') {
                                                                    if (new Date(customFieldList[j].split('||')[1]) != 'Invalid Date') {
                                                                        objStructured[customFieldList[j].split('||')[0]] = customFieldList[j].split('||')[1];
                                                                    }
                                                                    else {
                                                                        objStructured[customFieldList[j].split('||')[0]] = customFieldList[j].split('||')[1].split('/')[1] + '/' + customFieldList[j].split('||')[1].split('/')[0] + '/' + customFieldList[j].split('||')[1].split('/')[2];
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                                else {
                                                                    if (new Date(customFieldList[j].split('||')[4]) != 'Invalid Date') {
                                                                        objStructured[customFieldList[j].split('||')[0]] = new Date(customFieldList[j].split('||')[4]);
                                                                    }
                                                                    else {
                                                                        objStructured[customFieldList[j].split('||')[0]] = customFieldList[j].split('||')[4].split('/')[1] + '/' + customFieldList[j].split('||')[4].split('/')[0] + '/' + customFieldList[j].split('||')[4].split('/')[2];
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                            else {
                                                                objStructured[customFieldList[j].split('||')[0]] = customFieldList[j].split('||')[1];
                                                            }
                                                            checkExistance = checkExistance + "," + customFieldList[j].split('||')[0];
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                objStructured[defaultTaskColumnAray[10]] = data[i].GUID
                                                objStructured[defaultTaskColumnAray[11]] = data[i].ServiceRequestGUID
                                                structuredData.push(objStructured)
                                            }

                                            //Below code collapse all the panels of the panel bar
                                            panelbar.collapse($("li", panelbar.element));

                                            options.success(structuredData)
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            //Below code collapse all the panels of the panel bar
                                            panelbar.collapse($("li", panelbar.element));

                                            divSearchGrid.html('<h4>No records To Display</h4>')
                                            // To stop the Auto Refresh of the grid if there are no results
                                            isEditing = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        divSearchGrid.html('<h4>Some Error Occured</h4>')
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10
                },
                batch: true,
                groupable: true,
                scrollable: true,
                dataBound: GridDataBound,
                sortable: true,
                reorderable: true,
                resizable: true,
                selectable: "row",
                editable: true,
                columns: columnList,
                columnMenu: true,
                filterable: true,
                columnMenu: {
                    sortable: false
                },
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5,
                    pageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 100, 200]
                },
            });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of KendoUI are you using? I've tried to reproduce it in the following example : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/8k8NN/1/ and it works as you ask for (scroll for the columns). NOTE: this example is using 2013.2.712 (not even the last)

Comment: @OnaBai : Thanks for replying. I am using the latest version of the kendo UI , I saw your fiddle and that's what I need. But sadly not working for me.

Comment: My kendo version is 2013.3.1324

Comment: I can confirm @OnaBai example works for me.

Comment: @NitinRawat It is a problem with some Kendo Releases. Check my previous example with the release that you say in here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/8k8NN/2/ and the same with the latest release http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/8k8NN/3/

Comment: @OnaBai : Yes you are right, but with me the problem is that I can not change the version of kendo UI as there are some other problems with previous version because of which I upgraded it. can you provide any hack for this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This should sort you out:

```
.k-group .k-popup .k-reset 
{
max-height: 50px !important;
overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

Comment: Nopes , adding this piece of css doesn't help.

Comment: Works for me. Do you mind posting example of your code I'd like to see this "piece of css" doesn't do the job for you ?

Comment: I believe @OnaBai found the reason - its the kendo release, no need to trace the ghosts. If you are not ready to update your kendo version you advice to use the css provided in this answer or its equivalent in the OnaBais answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that was changed some KendoUI releases ago. Before, you had a limited vertical space and now you have all window. Shouldn't make too much difference since anyway you should have a vertical scroll.

Anyway, you can limit the amount of vertical spacing as @Bobby_D_ suggests but defining the scroll as:

```
.k-group.k-popup.k-reset {
    max-height: 200px !important;
}
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/8k8NN/6/

Comment: Even after putting this CSS it does not works for me. The scroll does not come at all.

Comment: Then it seems that you have some style or something very specific that is breaking it. In http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/8k8NN/7/ I've copied the different options that you used in the original question and it still works...

Answer (score 0):

Apply this rule

```css
li.k-item.k-columns-item.k-state-default.k-last > div>ul {overflow:auto !important}
```

and you will get something like this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
   .k-group.k-popup.k-reset {
    max-height: 350px !important; overflow:auto;
}
```